# Patterns binary classification - model doesn't overfit

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, python, hyper-parameters, architecture

I am working on a very basic binary classification problem. For each set of four float numbers $(x,y,z,w)$, I want to check if they fall or not into one category.

I have written a model with 3 dense layers (ReLU activation function) and an output layer (with sigmoid activation function). The model doesn't overfit, so I tried increasing the hyper-parameters, but still it doesn't overfit. I thought that reaching overfit was easy, as long as you increase the number of nodes. Isn't true?

Initially, I thought the problem was with the data, so I have decided to generate a mock dataset, but still the model doesn't overfit. In the code below, the function `generate_pattern()` generate a valid pattern that I want to label with the integer 1. I populate a Pandas dataframe with this function, and I add some noise by inserting random generated patterns.

Why is the model not overfitting? What is the best model's architecture for this kind of problems?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def generate_pattern():
    [x,y,z,w] = np.random.rand(4)/50
    return [0.35+x,0.45+y,0.7+z,1.32+w]

mock_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','z','w','target'])
i=0
while i < 10000:
    if np.random.randint(2) == 0:
        mock_data.loc[i] = generate_pattern() +[1]
        i+=1
    else:
        if np.random.randint(2) == 0:
            if np.random.randint(2) == 1:
                mock_data.loc[i] = list(np.random.rand(4)) + [0]
                i+=1

df_input = mock_data[['x','y','z','w']]
df_output = mock_data[['target']]
X = df_input.values
Y = df_output.astype(int).values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y[:,0], test_size=0.33, random_state=52)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.33, random_state=52)


# Create the neural network model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'], optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy','mean_squared_error','binary_crossentropy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=64, validation_data=(X_valid,y_valid))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is still in the way you generate the fake data.

Try to look at your generated features as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.jointplot(data=mock_data, x='x', y='y', hue='target')
# or
sns.jointplot(data=mock_data, x='z', y='w', hue='target')
```

The second plot yields:

[image]

that basically means that if your model learns the rule `(w > 1.1) and (z > 0.6)` it can achieve **perfect accuracy** whatever test data you use. This should imply that the problem is too simple, and so overfitting is very unlikely.